# How to save an Excel sheet as CSV so that no quotes are contained in the exported file?

Tags: csv, excel, excel-2003, vba

Okay, so I want to have a macro in Excel 2003 which saves the current worksheet as a .txt file. I've already got that part with the following code:

```
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
filename = InputBox("Please enter file name", "Save as CSV", "CSV_" & Format(Now, "DD_MM_yyyy"))
path = "C:\Temp" & filename & ".txt"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
```

But now to the actual problem: In my sheet there are some cells which contain a comma. If I use the macro shown above, the file gets saved as CSV, but the cells containing a comma have quotation marks around them. I do not want that.
If I save the file manually via File -> Save as -> CSV/TXT, the resulting file does not contain these quotation marks.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

Edit: I forgot to say that, when saving manually, I select Text tab-seperated, and not comma-seperated.

Comment: I highly doubt that a manual save doesn't contain the quotes. How are you viewing the resulting file?

Comment: I'm viewing the resulting file in Windows Notepad. Please also see my edit above; I want the files to be tab-seperated, not comma-seperated. Maybe xlTextMSDOS is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

OK, Let's see what I've got in the attic...

I have a VBA **Array To File** function which fits the bill: probably overkill for the work you're doing, as you don't need the options for header rows, transposing, and checking for pre-existing files with an error-trap that reads the file's datestamp and prevents repeated calls to the function continually overwriting the file. But it's the code I've got to hand, and simplifying it is more trouble than using it as-is.

The thing you *do* want is that this function uses the Tab character as a field delimiter by default. You could, of course, set it to the comma... The commonly-accepted definition of csv file is fields delimited by commas and text fields (which may contain the comma character) encapsulated in double-quotes. But I can't claim the moral high ground that would justify this kind of pedantry, because the code below doesn't impose the encapsulating quotes.

**Coding Notes:**

1. You need a reference to the Windows Scripting Runtime Library: scrrun.dll - this can be found in the system folder (usually C:\WINDOWS\system32) - as we're using the File System Object;
2. ArrayToFile writes the data to your named file in the temp folder. If you specify 'CopyFilePath', this will be copied elsewhere: never write to a network folder, it's always faster to write to a local drive and use the native file system functions to move or copy the finished file;
3. Data is written to the file in blocks, instead of line-by-line;
4. There is scope for further optimisation: using Split and Join functions would eliminate the string concatenations in the loops;
5. You might want to use VbCrLF as a row delimiter instead of VbCr: carriage returns usually work but some systems and applications need the Carriage-Return-and-LineFeed combination in order to read or display line breaks correctly.

**Using the ArrayToFile function:**

This is easy: just feed in the .Value2 property of the sheet's used range:

```
   ArrayToFile Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value2, "MyData.csv"
```

The reason for 'Value2' is that the 'Value' property captures formatting, and you probably want the underlying serial values of date fields.

**Source code for the VBA ArrayToFile function:**

Share and Enjoy... And watch out for helpful line breaks, inserted wherever they can break the code by your browser (or by StackOverflow's helpful formatting functions):

```
Public Sub ArrayToFile(ByVal arrData As Variant, _
                       ByVal strName As String, _
                       Optional MinFileAge As Double = 0, _
                       Optional Transpose As Boolean = False, _
                       Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr, _
                       Optional FieldDelimiter = vbTab, _
                       Optional CopyFilePath As String, _
                       Optional NoEmptyRows As Boolean = True, _
                       Optional arrHeader1 As Variant, _
                       Optional arrHeader2 As Variant)
```

' Output an array to a file. The field delimiter is tab (char 9); rows use CarriageReturn(char 13).
' The file will be named as specified by strName, and saved in the user's Windows Temp folder.

' Specify CopyFilePath (the full name and path) to copy this temporary file to another folder.
' Saving files locally and copying them is *much* faster than writing data across the network.

' If a Min File Age 'n' is specified, and n is greater than zero, an existing file will not be
' replaced, *and no data will be written* unless the file is more than MinFileAge seconds old.

' Transpose = TRUE is useful for arrays generated by Recordset.GetRows and ListControl.Column
' Note that ADODB.Recordset has a native 'save' method (rows delimited by VbCr, fields by Tab)

' **** This code is in the Public Domain **** Nigel Heffernan http://Excellerando.blogspot.com

On Error Resume Next

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Shell "Regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll", vbHide
    Application.Wait Now + (0.25 / 3600 / 24)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim strFile     As String
Dim strTemp     As String

Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim strData     As String
Dim strLine     As String

Dim strEmpty    As String
Dim dblCount    As Double

Const BUFFERLEN As Long = 255

strName = Replace(strName, "[", "")
strName = Replace(strName, "]", "")

Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Shell "Regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll", vbHide
    Application.Wait Now + (0.25 / 3600 / 24)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

strTemp = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(Scripting.TemporaryFolder).ShortPath

strFile = objFSO.BuildPath(strTemp, strName)

If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then

```
If MinFileAge > 0 Then
    If objFSO.GetFile(strFile).DateCreated + (MinFileAge / 3600 / 24) > Now Then
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Err.Clear
objFSO.DeleteFile strFile, True

If Err.Number = 70 Then
    VBA.FileSystem.Kill strFile
End If
```

End If

If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.StatusBar = "Cacheing data in a temp file... "

strData = vbNullString
With objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForWriting, True)

```
' **** **** **** HEADER1 **** **** ****
If Not IsMissing(arrHeader1) Then
If Not IsEmpty(arrHeader1) Then
If InStr(1, TypeName(arrHeader1), "(") > 1 Then  ' It's an array...

    Select Case ArrayDimensions(arrHeader1)
    Case 1  ' Vector array

       .Write Join(arrHeader1, RowDelimiter)

    Case 2 ' 2-D array... 3-D arrays are not handled

        If Transpose = True Then

            For i = LBound(arrHeader1, 2) To UBound(arrHeader1, 2)

                For j = LBound(arrHeader1, 1) To UBound(arrHeader1, 1)

                    strData = strData & FieldDelimiter & CStr(arrHeader1(j, i))

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

            Next i

       Else   ' not transposing:

            For i = LBound(arrHeader1, 1) To UBound(arrHeader1, 1)

                For j = LBound(arrHeader1, 2) To UBound(arrHeader1, 2)

                    strData = strData & CStr(arrHeader1(i, j))

                    If j &lt; UBound(arrHeader1, 2) Then
                        strData = strData & FieldDelimiter
                    End If

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

            Next i

        End If ' Transpose

    End Select


 '   .Write strData
 '   strData = vbNullString
    Erase arrHeader1

Else ' treat it as a string
    If LenB(arrHeader1) > 0 Then
        .Write arrHeader1
    End If
End If
End If 'Not IsMissing(arrHeader1)
End If 'Not IsEmpty(arrHeader1)



' **** **** **** HEADER2 **** **** ****
If Not IsMissing(arrHeader2) Then
If Not IsEmpty(arrHeader2) Then
If InStr(1, TypeName(arrHeader2), "(") > 1 Then  ' It's an array...

    Select Case ArrayDimensions(arrHeader2)
    Case 1  ' Vector array

       .Write Join(arrHeader2, RowDelimiter)

    Case 2 ' 2-D array... 3-D arrays are not handled

        If Transpose = True Then

            For i = LBound(arrHeader2, 2) To UBound(arrHeader2, 2)

                For j = LBound(arrHeader2, 1) To UBound(arrHeader2, 1)

                    strData = strData & FieldDelimiter & CStr(arrHeader2(j, i))

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

            Next i

       Else   ' not transposing:

            For i = LBound(arrHeader2, 1) To UBound(arrHeader2, 1)

                For j = LBound(arrHeader2, 2) To UBound(arrHeader2, 2)

                    strData = strData & CStr(arrHeader2(i, j))

                    If j &lt; UBound(arrHeader2, 2) Then
                        strData = strData & FieldDelimiter
                    End If

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

            Next i

        End If ' Transpose

    End Select        

 '   .Write strData
 '   strData = vbNullString
    Erase arrHeader2

Else ' treat it as a string
    If LenB(arrHeader2) > 0 Then
        .Write arrHeader2
    End If
End If
End If 'Not IsMissing(arrHeader2)
End If 'Not IsEmpty(arrHeader2)


' **** **** **** BODY **** **** ****

If InStr(1, TypeName(arrData), "(") > 1 Then
    ' It's an array...

    Select Case ArrayDimensions(arrData)
    Case 1

        If NoEmptyRows Then
            .Write Replace$(Join(arrData, RowDelimiter), RowDelimiter & RowDelimiter, "")
        Else
            .Write Join(arrData, RowDelimiter)
        End If

    Case 2

        If Transpose = True Then

            strEmpty = String(UBound(arrData, 1) - 1, FieldDelimiter) & RowDelimiter

            For i = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)

                For j = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)

                    strData = strData & FieldDelimiter & CStr(arrData(j, i))

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

                If (Len(strData) \ 1024) > BUFFERLEN Then

                    If NoEmptyRows Then
                        strData = Replace$(strData, strEmpty, "")
                        'strData = Replace$(strData, RowDelimiter & RowDelimiter, "")
                    End If

                    Application.StatusBar = "Cacheing data in a temp file... (" & Format(dblCount + (Len(strData) \ 1024), "0,000") & "kB)"

                    dblCount = dblCount + (Len(strData) \ 1024)
                    .Write strData
                    strData = vbNullString
                End If


            Next i

        Else   ' not transposing:

            strEmpty = String(UBound(arrData, 2) - 1, FieldDelimiter) & RowDelimiter

            For i = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)

                For j = LBound(arrData, 2) To UBound(arrData, 2)

                    strData = strData & CStr(arrData(i, j))

                    If j &lt; UBound(arrData, 2) Then
                        strData = strData & FieldDelimiter
                    End If

                Next j

                strData = strData & RowDelimiter

                If (Len(strData) \ 1024) > BUFFERLEN Then

                    If NoEmptyRows Then
                        strData = Replace$(strData, strEmpty, "")
                        'strData = Replace$(strData, RowDelimiter & RowDelimiter, "")
                    End If

                    Application.StatusBar = "Cacheing data in a temp file... (" & Format(dblCount + (Len(strData) \ 1024), "0,000") & "kB)"

                    dblCount = dblCount + (Len(strData) \ 1024)
                    .Write strData
                    strData = vbNullString
                End If

            Next i

        End If ' Transpose

    End Select

    If NoEmptyRows Then
        strData = Replace$(strData, strEmpty, "")
        'strData = Replace$(strData, RowDelimiter & RowDelimiter, "")
    End If

    If Right$(strData, Len(RowDelimiter)) = RowDelimiter Then
        Mid$(strData, Len(strData) - Len(RowDelimiter), Len(RowDelimiter)) = ""
    End If


    .Write strData
    strData = vbNullString
    Erase arrData

Else ' treat it as a string

     .Write arrData

End If
```

.Close
End With ' textstream object from objFSO.OpenTextFile

If CopyFilePath <> "" Then

```
Application.StatusBar = "Copying " & strName & " to " & CopyFilePath & "..."
objFSO.CopyFile strFile, CopyFilePath, True
```

End If

Application.StatusBar = False
Set objFSO = Nothing
strData = vbNullString

End Sub

For completeness, here's the complementary function that reads from files into an array, and a rough-and-ready subroutine to clean up your temp files:

Public Sub FileToArray(arrData As Variant, strName As String, Optional MaxFileAge As Double = 0, Optional RowDelimiter As String = vbCr, Optional FieldDelimiter = vbTab, Optional CoerceLowerBound As Long = 0) ' Load a file created by FileToArray into a 2-dimensional array
' The file name is specified by strName, and it is exected to exist in the user's temporary folder.
' This is a deliberate restriction: it's always faster to copy remote files to a local drive than to edit them across the network
' If a Max File Age 'n' is specified, and n is greater than zero, files more than n seconds old will NOT be read.

' **** This code is in the Public Domain **** Nigel Heffernan http://Excellerando.blogspot.com

On Error Resume Next

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Shell "Regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll", vbHide
    Application.Wait Now + (0.25 / 3600 / 24)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim strFile As String
Dim strTemp As String

Dim i   As Long
Dim j   As Long

Dim i_n As Long
Dim j_n As Long

Dim i_lBound As Long
Dim i_uBound As Long
Dim j_lBound As Long
Dim j_uBound As Long

Dim arrTemp1 As Variant
Dim arrTemp2 As Variant

Dim dblCount As Double

Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Shell "Regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll", vbHide
    Application.Wait Now + (0.25 / 3600 / 24)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

strTemp = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(Scripting.TemporaryFolder).ShortPath

strFile = objFSO.BuildPath(strTemp, strName)

If Not objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If MaxFileAge > 0 Then
    ' If the file's a bit elderly, bail out - the calling function will refresh the data from source
    If objFSO.GetFile(strFile).DateCreated + (MaxFileAge / 3600 / 24) < Now Then
        Set objFSO = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If

End If

Application.StatusBar = "Reading the file... (" & strName & ")"

arrData = Split2d(objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading).ReadAll, RowDelimiter, FieldDelimiter, CoerceLowerBound)

Application.StatusBar = "Reading the file... Done"

Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub

Public Sub RemoveTempFiles(ParamArray FileNames())

On Error Resume Next

Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Shell "Regsvr32.exe /s scrrun.dll", vbHide
    Application.Wait Now + (0.25 / 3600 / 24)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If

If objFSO Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim varName As Variant
Dim strName As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTemp As String

strTemp = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(Scripting.TemporaryFolder).ShortPath

For Each varName In FileNames

```
strName = vbNullString
strFile = vbNullString

strName = CStr(varName)
strFile = objFSO.BuildPath(strTemp, strName)

If objFSO.FileExists(strFile) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile strFile, True
End If
```

Next varName

Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub

I'd advise you to keep this in a module under Option Private Module -  this isn't the kind of function I'd want other users calling from a worksheet directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible (sort of).

A field that contains the delimiter must be enclosed in quotes. Otherwise, that field would be "torn in two" by the delimiter.

The only solution is to use a different delimiter, for example tabs (effectively changing it to a TSV file), which of course only works if that new delimiter doesn't occur in the data either.

Comment: I'm sorry that I forgot an important fact when first asking my question; please see my edit above. I don't want to use the comma as the delimiter, but instead tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the `SaveAs` formats work for you, write your parser, eg

```
Sub SaveFile()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim ln As Variant

    ' Set rng to yout data range, eg
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Open "C:\Temp\TESTFILE.txt" For Output As #1    ' Open file for output.
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        ln = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rw)), vbTab)
        Print #1, ln; vbNewLine;
    Next
    Close #1
End Sub
```